# NServiceBus not publishing to MSMQ

Tags: nservicebus5

I am doing a pilot to test Publisher/Subscriber pattern of NServiceBus using the following code.
**I wished to test the Publish function INDEPENDENTLY first.**
However my messages are logged into the error log every time I run the publisher independently.

***Program.cs of Publisher.proj***

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        LogManager.Use<DefaultFactory>().Level(LogLevel.Info);
        BusConfiguration busConfiguration = new BusConfiguration();
        busConfiguration.EndpointName("Samples.PubSub.MyPublisher");
        busConfiguration.UseSerialization<XmlSerializer>();
        busConfiguration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();
        busConfiguration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
        busConfiguration.EnableInstallers();
        using (IBus bus = Bus.Create(busConfiguration).Start())
        {
            bus.Subscribe<EventMessage>();
            Start(bus);
        }
    }

    static void Start(IBus bus)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press '1' to publish IEvent");
        Console.WriteLine("Press '2' to publish EventMessage");
        Console.WriteLine("Press '3' to publish AnotherEventMessage");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to publish a message.To exit, Ctrl + C");
        #region PublishLoop
        while (true)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine();

            Guid eventId = Guid.NewGuid();
            switch (key.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.D1:
                    bus.Publish<IMyEvent>(m =>
                    {
                        m.EventId = eventId;
                        //m.Time = DateTime.Now.Second > 30 ? (DateTime?) DateTime.Now : null;
                        m.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(99999D);
                    });
                    Console.WriteLine("Published IMyEvent with Id {0}.", eventId);
                    continue;
                case ConsoleKey.D2:

                    EventMessage eventMessage = new EventMessage
                    {
                        EventId = eventId,
                        Time = DateTime.Now.Second > 30 ? (DateTime?) DateTime.Now : null,
                        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(99999D)
                    };
                    bus.Publish(eventMessage);
                    Console.WriteLine("Published EventMessage with Id {0}.", eventId);
                    continue;
                case ConsoleKey.D3:
                    AnotherEventMessage anotherEventMessage = new AnotherEventMessage
                    {
                        EventId = eventId,
                        Time = DateTime.Now.Second > 30 ? (DateTime?) DateTime.Now : null,
                        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(99999D)
                    };
                    bus.Publish(anotherEventMessage);
                    Console.WriteLine("Published AnotherEventMessage with Id {0}.", eventId);
                    continue;
                default:
                    return;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

***App.config of Publisher.proj***

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="AuditConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.AuditConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="Shared" Endpoint="Samples.PubSub.MyPublisher"/>
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
  <AuditConfig QueueName="audit" />
</configuration>  "
```

***Error :***
2015-11-22 21:57:01.264 WARN  NServiceBus.Faults.Forwarder.FaultManager Message
with '396bf681-f7b7-44f7-88b6-a5580169b865' id has failed FLR and will be handed
 over to SLR for retry attempt 1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your message def's in the code you provided.

Try putting them in their own assembly, and referencing it, then update your UniBusConfig to something like:

```
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Assembly="Samples.PubSub.Shared" 
           Endpoint="Samples.PubSub.MyPublisher" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

Retry your code.

See http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/message-owner for more details.